# functional programming efficiency vs imperative

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming and I just ran into something and was wondering if there was a way around this.

Suppose I have

```
myArray = [
  { a : 1 }
  { a : 4 }
  { a : 5 }
  { a : 6 }
  { a : 7 }
  { a : 8 }
]
```

Let say I need to do statistical operations on this data set such as

```
const median = myArray[ Math.ceil( myArray.length / 2 ) ]['a'] // Math.ceil .. Side Effect?
const fiveOrMore = myArray.filter( value => value.a >= 5 )
const lessThanFive = myArray.filter( value => value.a < 5 )
```

Some arbitrary examples. 
The problem with this as of right now is that with increasing amount of statistical operations I need to do, the efficiency decreases.

With imperative style, I could do everything in **ONE** for loop. Is this the wrong approach to functional programming that I am taking or is it a **trade off** of functional programming paradigm itself?

Comment: Do you mean `.a` on the first line?

Comment: @Hassan first line?

Comment: As in, instead of the `[a]`.

Comment: @Hassan just fixed.

Comment: The first question that should **always** be asked in these situations is: how big is your dataset, does any of this matter? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Knuth.

Comment: @ASDFGerte The dataset will range from 0 to 200 maximum most likely.

Comment: So if you aren't doing this operation thousands of times per second, all operations you have shown in your question take negligible amount of time to compute.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thanks, but what happens if data set becomes substantially large?

Comment: This is slightly opinionated.  However, some functional executions *can* read slightly easier because you can look at the code and say, "these are the exact operations being applied, in order, to this dataset without side effects".  Of course I've seen some really obtuse applications of `reduce` and `filter` that are counter examples.

Comment: @ASDFGerte While I agree about premature optimization, there is nothing wrong with striving for good CS design. If there is no way for functional programming to do something so simple in a single pass ( n vs 2n), I'd consider it a strike against it and worth bearing in mind. Which is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @dgeare "negligible" means exactly what it means - if it is clear the dataset will be small, no consideration should be given towards performance at all. If you consider it a "strike against [the functional approach]" then imho you are making a mistake. Readability and other factors should be considered (which may still favor another style in some cases, but that's completely unrelated to performance).

Comment: Thank guys I think got what I needed. Just wondering if the data set was large enough and functional programming lowered performance, would you ditch it altogether?

Comment: There are cases where this becomes an issue, and yes, last but least, non-functional hand-optimized iterative code will usually beat the functional counterpart. However, this is rarely a problem. I'd say in most cases, the order of the algorithm used and other potential mistakes play a bigger role and should therefore get considerably more attention. From what i know, calculations are either negligibly short or so far out of reach that a factor of ten wouldn't make a difference either.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thanks! I am more inclined towards the functional programming paradigm over the imperative as well.

Comment: To make one last thing clear: the size of the data together with the order of the algorithm used matters. If you have an algorithm in O(2**n) - exponential order - a dataset of size 200 will already be devastating. A factor of ten would not save you there either though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is of course less performant. And the performance hit *is* a trade off of the style you chose.

One may argue that it's not a big deal since the time complexity is `O(n)`, [the only difference is the constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant). I'd say make sure you preformance-test your app. If it's slow -- it's time to optimize certain blocks of code.

Premature optimization is evil. There will be many cases where imperative code works faster or much faster of muchly much faster than the functional one, and depending on the case you may or may not be okay with that.

Also, there are various techniques to improve the performance. You don't necessarily want to change the style. Say, in some cases [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) can drastically boost the speed of the function, while keeping the code functional. Just think outside the box.

Comment: I would clarify "side effect" whenever you use it to talk about functional programming.  "trade off" might be the more appropriate term.

Comment: So really this is a trade off between the readability and variety of other things that functional programming brings vs efficiency. And from what people are saying is that if the data set is small, it's negligible.

Comment: @Aaron "And from what people are saying is that if the data set is small, it's negligible" Right. Here's an example. In JavaScript, arrays shorter than 10 arrays are sorted with a slower InsertionSort algorithm; whereas, the longer are sorted with a faster QuickSort. This is because, we can judge about performance quite differently depending on many many factors including the size of the input...

Answer (score 4):

With functional style you could have done it in one reduce too. Just have a function that checks the element is below and the accumulator would be a structure with two lists you are adding elements to.

If you are thinking about passing a list through a series of higher order functions then you can reduce overhead with [Trancducers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mTbuzafcII) which basically works like individual `map`, `filter` but with no lists between the operations.

There are [streams](https://github.com/winterbe/sequency) which employ lazy evaluation if perhaps you will not be using all the elements in your result.

And there are [generators](https://dev.to/nestedsoftware/lazy-evaluation-in-javascript-with-generators-map-filter-and-reduce--36h5). Basically you can make several `for` loops and use `ỳield` to "return" a value and you can chain these since all generators can be iterated with `for of`. Also here you can halt whenever you have enough data.

So for all these there are pros and cons. Performance wise if you are going to calculate all the elements anyway using generators and streams will have a bit overhead. Transducers is perhaps the better option that gives composability with little list making, but the loop will of course be faster.

Testing is easier with functional implementations and you can test individual stages isolated. One very large loop that rules the whole app is often difficult to debug. This also goes when you have one `reduce` which just rewrites one loop in a functional style.

Comment: _With functional style you could have done it in one reduce too_ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLmVTr9hq8Q

Answer (score 2):

You can cram things into one loop in either functional or imperative style.  In *both* styles it hurts readability.  In *both* styles your compiler can do [loop fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_fission_and_fusion) to eliminate the extra loop.  Also, a single loop is not always faster, and a compiler will be able to discern the situations where fusion is appropriate better than humans easily can.

As Sylwester pointed out, functional programming has many techniques that let you write loops separately but execute them together.  Functional style is also easier to explicitly parallelize onto multiple threads.

There are also often library functions that already do what you want in a single loop, and are both more descriptive and more concise.  For example, your last two lines can be done with a [partition](http://underscorejs.org/#partition):

```
_.partition(myArray, x => x['a'] < 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my mottos is:

> "I don't care how fast I can compute the wrong answer."

I might try and write some super-fast-code but its a risk if my code is hard understand and thus easy to introduce bugs / hard to spot errors. Unless the code is super critical to execution speed, I opt for the approach that makes it most easy to express what I'm trying to do: sometimes the functional approach can make your intent very clear, whilst in other situations imperative is more appropriate.

Once I have code that works, and passes a set of unit tests, I can then rewrite in search of more speed if required.

As an aside, this is why I'm enjoying Swift at present - I have both functional and imperative options available. Oh, and I know its not pure functional, but with my engineering rather than computer science hat on, its close enough! ;-)